# Having Some issue in div tag

Tags: html, css

I am using div tag in my code. I have set the class for this when I used height for this working fine, but I want it to expand without using height

```
<div id="list-div-bg">

 <div class="list-view-photo">
 <img src="images/list-img.png" alt="" width="77" height="63">
 </div>

<div id="list-view-text"> 
 Nissan Pulsar LS Euro Series<br>
<span class="Stock-title">Stock Number: 7407<br>
Transmission: Automatic<br></span>
<a href="#" class="link-text">More Details</a></div>


<div class="price-div"> $9,499
  <br>
  Available<br> 
  <a href="#" class="save-button"> SAVE</a> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it me or didn't you realize this is not CSS -`<img src="images/list-img.png" alt="" width="77" height="63">`?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "expand without using height?"

Set height to auto(Default). OR use "%" to Define the height in percent of the containing block.